# How to disable WAL journal mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, persistent-storage, wal

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/WhatsNew_CoreData_iOS/

I am having trouble in disabling journal mode.

My code is:

```
static NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext(){
static NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
if (context != nil) {
    return context;
}

NSString * const NSSQLitePragmasOption;

NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE" };

@autoreleasepool {
    context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel()];
    [context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    
    NSString *STORE_TYPE = NSSQLiteStoreType;

    NSString *path = @"ExerciseDB";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[path stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"sqlite"]];
 
    NSError *error;
    NSPersistentStore *newStore = [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:STORE_TYPE configuration:nil URL:url options:NSSQLitePragmasOption error:&error];
    
    if (newStore == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Store Configuration Failure %@", ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
    }
}
return context;
}
```

How would I go about disabling journal mode WAL.

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To disable WAL mode, set the journal_mode to DELETE

```
NSMutableDictionary *pragmaOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"DELETE" forKey:@"journal_mode"];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, pragmaOptions, NSSQLitePragmasOption, nil];
[_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]
```

Comment: Rats, I tried doing this, but it just causes a failure to read the database. :(

Answer (score 14):

From Apple Technical Documentation: [Technical Q&A QA1809](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1809/_index.html)

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:@{@"journal_mode":@"DELETE"}};
if (! [persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                            configuration:nil
                                            URL:storeURL
                                            options:options
                                            error:&error]) {
    // error handling.
}
```

Edit 2020:

### **SwiftUI + iOS 14 (Xcode 12 beta 6)**

When you create a new project with SwiftUI and check CoreData template, your new project has this code in *Persistence.swift* file:

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    //...

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "db_name")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                //...
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Now, you can add the following block of code after init container (`container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "db_name")`)

```
if let url = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first?.url {
    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: url)
    storeDescription.setValue("DELETE" as NSObject, forPragmaNamed: "journal_mode")
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2 it would be the following:

```
    let dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
        NSSQLitePragmasOption: ["journal_mode":"DELETE"]
    ]

    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: dict)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as! NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }
```