# Issue in viewing sqlite file created by Core Data in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue when am trying to access the database file that is created by core data. The DB file is in Documents folder. I've copied this to my desktop and opened it using Firefox plug in. **`Hello.sqlite` file doesn't contain any rows** that I have **inserted values using core data**. Am running app using iOS 7 simulator. I can see the rows are inserted when am using iOS-6. Do any body have an idea, why I cant see values in my `Hello.sqlite file`????

Comment: It doesn't make sense. Are you sure that, you have looking the exact file of the IOS7 Simulator .

Comment: You can't directly see records in .sqlite file need to .mom model file so that refer my answer i use this technique to show sqlite data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view your project data do the following:

1. Run your xcode project on your Mac (Must have a database included)
2. Launch CoreDataPro
3. Select Menu->File->New Project
4. Select the "File" tab you could use file tab and browse to "/Users/UserName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/CD000457-0F95-4AFF-9C0A-829F681557AF(select like wise folder)"/your application" copy and paste on Desktop
5. Step 2: Persistence  file load that is your .sql File
6. copy .sqlite file from  where you can store (i.e /Users/Your User Name/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/CD000457-0F95-4AFF-9C0A-829F681557AF/Documents)
7. Select Open
8. Browse your Application data

[Download from Wiki](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility/wiki)

[For More detail Visit here](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility)

[Direct Coredata Download Link](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility/wiki/CoreDataPro.app_2013123000.zip)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of a new SQLite journal mode used in iOS 7. If you set it to the old mode as shown in the answer to the following SO question you should see your data again.

[How to disable WAL journal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062197/how-to-disable-wal-journal-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below link is useful for u
http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/ios-core-data-tutorial-with-example/