# Saving of managed object context failed RestKit0.20+CoreData

Tags: core-data, ios7, restkit-0.20

I am migrating my connection classes to support Caching via CoreData. RestKit does it automagically using RKEntityMapping. RestKit and CoreData did the mapping and validation correctly, I got a bunch of NSManagedObject I requested for but it is not saving the objects to the CoreData. When I check the logs, I got this.

```
W restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:776 Saving of managed object context failed, but a `nil` value for the `error` argument was returned. This typically indicates an invalid implementation of a key-value validation method exists within your model. This violation of the API contract may result in the save operation being mis-interpretted by callers that rely on the availability of the error.
E restkit.network.core_data:RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.m:818 Failed saving managed object context to the persistent store <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x145e5ce0>: (null)
```

I don't have an idea, why is this occurring. I checked my Model for wrong settings or attributes but I can't find any. As I observed, NSManagedObjects is saved InMemory (NSFetchResultsController was still able to fetch the objects even when I leave the view. So I guess, the objects were saved InMemory). Can someone help me find what is wrong here. Leaving any tips for debugging the problem is welcome. Thank you.

I had this code to setup the core data.

```
- (void)setupCoreData
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [[AppDelegate sharedDelegate] managedObjectModel];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] setManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

    NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Model.sqlite"];

    NSError *error;

    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil  withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

    // Create the managed object contexts
    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

    // Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
}
```

This is called before I add all response/request descriptors. I generated the model class using MoGenerator. I override some setters and did some validations before inserting (validateForInsert).

Comment: Show code for your core data stack configuration. Do you have any KVC validations?

Comment: I don't have any KVO here, I just override some setters.

Comment: KVC and KVO are 2 very different things. What about the stack configuration?

Comment: Ok, so next to look at are your `validateForInsert` implementations.

Comment: Please check whether any data is inserted using CoreDataPro?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276249/issue-in-viewing-sqlite-file-created-by-core-data-in-ios-7