# CoreData with shared UIManagedDocument - Cocoa error 134030: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, uimanageddocument

In my iOS 7+ app I'm using `Core Data` with a *single shared* `UIManagedDocument`. I know that this approach is [not recommended anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21339572/1677480) and that one should use standard `Core Data` stack, but I would love to know what is happening in this case.

As I said, I'm using *single shared* `UImanagedDocument`, implemented like described in this [blog post](http://themainthread.com/blog/2012/03/core-data-with-a-single-shared-uimanageddocument.html). Quite randomly, after many "concurrent" writing and reading on `UIManagedDocument` instance I get following error in `UIDocument` overriden method `- (void)handleError:userInteractionPermitted:`:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
(Cocoa error 134030.)" UserInfo=0x14ea16e0 {NSAffectedStoresErrorKey=(
"<NSSQLCore: 0x14d9a0b0> (URL: file:///var/mobile/Applications/8C70F46C-74DB-427B-8DE2-68A36B326CA7/Library/CoreDataDatabase/StoreContent/persistentStore)"), NSUnderlyingError=0x14e8ca10 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)\" 
UserInfo=0x14e1b7d0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x14eb3d90 \"The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. No such file or directory\"}"
```

Through the app I'm saving my document with `[document saveToURL:document.fileURL forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:NULL];`.

Error is emerged after the document switches to `UIDocumentStateSavingError` state.

I've tried re-opening my document after that but it didn't work. Looks like the `persistent store` is being deleted (at least that is what an error is suggesting) but I don't have a single clue why.

Thanks in advance!