# Error updating SQlite database in ios7

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios7

I've got a problem with an update of an SQLite database in iOS7. I think it might be as a result of the lack of a wal file on the new db version, but I might be wrong, as the error is the same when I load i=either the ios6.1 or the iOS 7.0 simulator. I have the simulator loading a local file, using the following code:

```
    NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NLancs" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbPath];
    // set up for iphone with SQL database in local files. If using simulator comment out "NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NLancs" ofType:@"sqlite"];" and "[NSURL fileURLWithPath:dbPath];"  above and remove comment from line below
   //[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"NLancs.sqlite"];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{ @"journal_mode" : @"DELETE" } },nil];
```

On running the app in the simulator I get the following error:

> 2014-03-15 15:57:22.974 North Lancashire CCG[40813:907] AppDelegate
>   Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named Condition
>   2014-03-15 15:57:22.981 North Lancashire CCG[40813:907] AppDelegate
>   created new MOM 2014-03-15 15:57:23.056 North Lancashire
>   CCG[40813:907] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=259 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 259.)"
>   UserInfo=0xa48a7f0 {NSUnderlyingException=An error occurred converting
>   the metadata plist: Unexpected character a at line 1}, {
>       NSUnderlyingException = "An error occurred converting the metadata plist: Unexpected character a at line 1"; } (lldb)

I've also tried creating an empty database in the simulator, which runs fine. How do I replace it with the populated database without tripping over wal files? The populated database opens fine in SQLite Professional, but if I overwrite the empty simulator database with it, I get the following error (with or without .wal or .shm deleted):

> ```
> 2014-03-15 16:14:32.855 North Lancashire CCG[43265:70b] AppDelegate Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity
> ```
>
> named Condition
>       2014-03-15 16:14:32.857 North Lancashire CCG[43265:70b] The application Document Directory is:
>       2014-03-15 16:14:32.870 North Lancashire CCG[43265:70b] AppDelegate created new MOM
>       2014-03-15 16:14:32.893 North Lancashire CCG[43265:70b] CoreData: error: (11) Fatal error.  The database at
>   /Users/Neil/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/BD12C12C-2DA2-4164-BCAE-B42A2064AABC/Documents/NLancs.sqlite
>   is corrupted.  SQLite error code:11, 'database disk image is
>   malformed'

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried turning off [WAL journal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062197/how-to-disable-wal-journal-mode)

Comment: Thanks - I ended up fixing this by doing a CSV data import into the empty simulator database. So I got around the problem, even if I didn't fix the root cause