# SQLCipher, encrypted-core-data and iOS - are two .sqlite-files normal?

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord, sqlcipher, encrypted-core-data-sql

I'm using SQLCipher to encrypt my database as there's sensitive information. Everything seems to work, I'm just irritated because I've got two .sqlite-files right now:

```
~/Library/Application Support/MyData.sqlite
~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/MyData.sqlite
~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/MyData.sqlite-shm
~/Library/Application Support/MyApp/MyData.sqlite-wal
```

The first one is encrypted, the second isn't - but it doesn't contain any information. So it seems to work as there's no way to get to the information, but I just wanted to ensure that this is correct.

Comment: What are shm and wal files it was already explained many times. Duplicate eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870387/core-data-and-ios-7-different-behavior-of-persistent-store

Comment: yes, I don't care much about the shm- and wal-files, but more on the two .sqlite-files, i.e. - why are there two sqlite files?

Comment: If you delete the app from the simulator and then reinstall it, do you get two `.sqlite` files every time?

Comment: That does not seem correct. The -shm and -wal files are from WAL and can safely be ignored. However, that doesn't explain the existence of 2 different MyData.sqlite databases. @swalkner does the first database contain any data? What are the datestamps on the files? Are you sure one isn't left over from before you were using SQLCipher?

Comment: Are both your app and Core Data model called MyData? At least with encrypted-core-data (which uses SQLCipher) you will see an empty (schema only) database for each model with the model name and another db which will contain all the encrypted data named as the project itself (ie. model1.sqlite, model2.sqlite, Project.sqlite).

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to turn off the Write Ahead Logging feature of sqlite. To do this in Core Data, you need to set a pragma option on your store. You can see how to set the flag from this [related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062197/how-to-disable-wal-journal-mode)

Comment: That wouldn't account for the two `.sqlite` files, though.

Comment: Those files are an artifact related to write ahead logging. Disabling the feature for a store will not create them in the first place. This feature was enabled by default by the CoreData framework in iOS7.

Comment: This does not answer the question, **why there are two sqlite files**.