# Save large amount of Data into CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

I want to **save** the large amount of data into **CoreData**, The resource of my Data is in ***CSV*** format.

I know the following ways to achieve it.

1. With Help of **Multiple MOC** - I already tried with this one but its only help me to not freeze the my app on **Main thread**, Actually after the splash I want to use that data as well and while data is being save at background thread - Chances to not have that data immediately on required screen(***Actually even I faced it, I was not able to fetch entity I want - Perhaps still its remaining to save on CoreData stack?***)
2. Do I need to convert that file into **plist extension** file? Is that the good idea to store large amount of data in plist file? And unfortunately I was not able to find any ***online tool*** which converts my **.csv** file to **.plist file?** I guess reading the data from plist is not a big deal.
3. **Preloaded database** need to be import into CoreData, Right now I am working by this way, I successfully converted my CSV file to SQLite file and imported it to bundle and then copy it from the bundle to Document Directory while **NSPersistentContainer** will be **initialize**. Now I have some few queries on this point as below.

   - I found the **SQLite** file inside Document Directory, But its actually
     just **copy** the **Existing SQLite's Tables with My CoreData Entities**,
     What I want is that One of Table from Existing SQLite should be **merge**
     with My **CoreData Entity**, Do I need to loop over the table for each
     row and then manually save it to Entity? If so then its the same
     situation as I mentioned at Point 1.?
   - Somewhere I found that **CoreData DB structure** *and* **SQLite DB structure** are different, so What I did - I created some Dummy Data
     on CoreData and Found the SQLite file, Inside that SQLite file I
     **imported** the data from **CSV Table** and now That SQLite file I have used
     in **application bundle**, I guess here I **achieved** something as I got an
     **error** says ***migration Failed as Table already exist on Database***, **Don't**
     I need to **define Entity** first into DataModel?, OR **Don't** I need to
     **Create** the table inside SQLite File?(***If so then Where I can
     pre-populate the Data?***)

***Please suggest What I Need to Do? And how can I achieve it? Also It would be great if you suggest any other options to Do so.***

Comment: Select one of all of your questions and ask that. Right now this is way too broad. And take it easy with the bold font.

Comment: Edit your question and remove irrelevant information so it is clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

To extract an entity-aware version of your SQLite database files, you can run your app in a simulator and print out to the console the path to the file generated.  Then using Finder retrieve the file after Core Data is done parsing/saving all the records.

You can then bundle up the generated SQLite file in your projects and have it ready to use.

Comment: I tried by your way and its still not working, I also added three files into bundle as 1) .sqlite 2) .sqlite-shm 3) .sqlite-wal

Comment: @GOPALVASANI because you don't remove journal mode for Core Data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062197/how-to-disable-wal-journal-mode/20082157

Answer (score 0):

I think it solution is bad. Because you make few problem
1) Your build will be more size - and you don't fix this. And user would be loading app too long time.
2) You will be have sqlite file in bundle application, it means you can't change this Database in runtime.

It can be fix with two way:
1 way - make two Core Data stack one readonly, second read/write with sqlite in application support directory. But it complicates work with the Core Data. And it way available only if your don't need change data how stored in app bundle.
2 way - make copy sqlite file to application directory, and work with this. But you will have two copy of one file.

If you sure in this way
1) You need make simple parser what work only debag mode and simulator.
2) You should setup Core Data with off journal mode (we need only sqlite file)
[How to disable WAL journal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062197/how-to-disable-wal-journal-mode/20082157)

```
options["journal_mode"] = "DELETE"
```

More information about journal mode
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1809/_index.html

3) Parsing your scv and get sqlite file in Simulator
4) Add sqlite file in your resources

But I recommend make API requests, how send data in your application
1) You can send some hash or last update and receive only diff data (not all)
2) You can ask only data how need at this moment with pagination data and support hash.