# CoreData: annotation: PostSaveMaintenance: fileSize greater than prune

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I got this message from CoreData while updating my app's database.

```
CoreData: annotation: PostSaveMaintenance: fileSize 9216472 greater than prune threshold
CoreData: annotation: PostSaveMaintenance: wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)
```

What does it mean?

Does it corrupt my data (by truncation)?

How can I set a breakpoint to catch when this happens?

Comment: I don't think you can set a breakpoint here since this is Core Data internal but you could activate debug logging for Core Data by giving the launch argument `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`, the level can be from 1 to 4 and I normally use 1 but I read in an article in relation to this that it should be set to 4.

Comment: `wal_checkpoint(TRUNCATE)`, Core Data (actually SQlite) uses something called Write-Ahead Logging (WAL) that somewhat simplified means that SQlite write changes to a separate file (.wal) instead of directly to the database for improved perforemance and this `wal_checkpoint` command is executed to move changes from the file to the database.

Comment: Do you have some attributes of type Data or String in any of your entities that can become very large? Not sure if this is the cause of it but I seen some reference to large blobs when googling this.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I store images in CoreData.  But these should be up to a few hundred kB max.  I'll check.  Thanks for the launch argument suggestion, will try that as well!

Comment: Did you fine any solution? I'm struggling with the same.

Comment: Did you try disable WAL mode? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261845/3401995