# How to preload data into SwiftData model?

Tags: swift, swift-data

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData


@Model class Example: {
    let name: String
    let type: String

    init(name: String, type: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
    }
}

//Then in the View

@Query var doors: [Door]
```

SwiftData is the new framework from Apple at WWDC 20223 and this might be a silly question but I can't seem to figure out a best practice here. I can have the user add Examples but I can't see how to add them at the code level.

```
extension Example {
    static let examples: [Example] = [
        Example(
            name: "ex1",
            type: "red"
            ),
        Example(
            name: "ex2",
            type: "blue"
            )
    ]
}
```

I tried preloading the data with an extension but that didn't get passed down to the view. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 11):

Thanks everyone but found a great answer to my question here!

https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/blog/ios-development/data-persistence/pre-populate-swiftdata-persistent-store/

This blog details how to use @MainActors to Accomplish this function

```
@MainActor
let appContainer: ModelContainer = {
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: Item.self)
        
        // Make sure the persistent store is empty. If it's not, return the non-empty container.
        var itemFetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>()
        itemFetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = 1
        
        guard try container.mainContext.fetch(itemFetchDescriptor).count == 0 else { return container }
        
        // This code will only run if the persistent store is empty.
        let items = [
            Item(timestamp: Date()),
            Item(timestamp: Date()),
            Item(timestamp: Date())
        ]
        
        for item in items {
            container.mainContext.insert(object: item)
        }
        
        return container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to create container")
    }
}()
```

Comment: Makes sense happy to add more detail.

Comment: Worked great, just needed to change this

```let container = try ModelContainer(
            for: Player.self, configurations: ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
        )```

Comment: I started using this but now Xcode is giving me a warning that this will be invalid in Swift6 because the `appContainer` cannot by marked as `@MainActor`. And when I remove it, then it complains that the `mainContext.fetch()` needs to be `@MainActor` isolated.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach, for example, in `.onAppear()` if there are no `examples` already load them in, as in the example code:

```
.onAppear {
    if examples.isEmpty {
        for ex in Example.examples {
            modelContext.insert(ex)   // <--- here
        }
    }
}
```

You could also read the initial data from a file and load the `examples` into `SwiftData`, the first time the app is used. There are many ways, and at the end use something like : `modelContext.insert(...)`

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative approach, you can create a pre-filled store, add it to the bundle, and work with this file. If you only need to add a few data items, you can follow [workingdog answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76544203/3401995). However, if you need to insert a large amount of data, this can be a good approach.

Here's how to do it:

**1.** Run your app, inserting all the data. Following your example:

```
.onAppear {
    let array = Example.examples
    guard !array.isEmpty {
        array.forEach { example in
            modelContext.insert(example)
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** Navigate to the *Library/Application Support* folder of simulator. It should be something like:

```
/Users/nes8/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C975335B-C557-64D8-ABAB-2E6CAA123FFC/data/Containers/Data/Application/28EDB452-B8E8-6FBF-8C69-B48BD421442D/Library/Application Support
```

You might find it easier to locate by searching for *default.store* in Finder.

**3.** In this folder, you will see three files related to your database:

- default.store
- default.store-shm
- default.store-wal

[image]

When I saw the -wal file, I was concerned about whether the write-ahead logging (WAL) journal was activated by default. Fortunately, I'm using Xcode 15.0 beta 8, and it isn't the case. If you see that the default.store-wal file size is zero, there's no need to worry about it. If not, you may need to disable WAL mode. You can find instructions on how to do that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20062197/how-to-disable-wal-journal-mode), but as of writing this example, there isn't an answer specific to SwiftData.

**4.** Copy *default.store* into your Xcode project. Remember select 'add to targets'

If you've inserted a significant amount of data, you may notice a large file size for this file. As you can see in the previous image, I loaded a substantial amount of data without any issues.

[image]

**5.** When you create a ModelContainer in your main struct App, you can initialize a ModelConfiguration with a schema and URL. To do this, simply get the URL of your store. Here's a sample code snippet that Xcode provides when you create a new project with SwiftData selected:

```
@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Example.self,
        ])

        // get url
        let urlPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "default", withExtension: "store")!
        // load store from url
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, url: urlPath)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()
...
```

**IMPORTANT:**

- If you change your Models, you must repeat all the steps as the schema will change.
- Only perform this procedure during the first app launch. After that, if you modify any data, the app will create a copy of your store in the system folder (Application Support). So, after that, just load a "normal" configuration:

```
let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
```

Comment: I tried this approach and it worked when I load the default.store with existing data, but I soon as I add a new record, it is not persisted.

I'm only calling
```let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, url: urlPath)```
on the first launch. After that I start it with 
```let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)```

Comment: You need to copy dataStore from bundle to the Documents directory first, and point the url to it, if you want to be able to modify it.