# How to preload SwiftData into model with async operation?

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-data

I was reading this post, [How to Preload Data into SwiftData Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76543560/how-to-preload-data-into-swiftdata-model) and it worked great, but because I want to load the data from an [external json file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yuhonas/free-exercise-db/main/dist/exercises.json) via an API call I get the expected error of `'async' call cannot occur in a property initializer`.

I saw there might be some solutions where you initialize the container first and then update it later using the @StateObject but I think this is not solving the problem because its not a true preload.

Is there a way to use the SwiftData container in this asynchronous way or would I only be able to load the data via a local csv or json file?

```swift
@main
@MainActor
struct AnvilApp: App {
    let appContainer: ModelContainer = {
        do {
            let container = try ModelContainer(for: Exercise.self)
            
            // load in exercises
            let url = URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yuhonas/free-exercise-db/main/dist/exercises.json")!
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let exercises = try JSONDecoder().decode([Exercise].self, from: data)
            
            for exercise in exercises {
                container.mainContext.insert(exercise)
            }
            
            return container
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to create container")
        }
    }() // The "()" here runs the closure immediately
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(appContainer)
    }
}
```